# How to make Interface available in all Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a number of Controllers, and I want them all to have an interface to a `PageConfiguration` object that needs to be created based on the URL. I'm not sure how to do this other than to create the interface in the action methods, because they have access to `Request.QueryString`, where the Controllers constructors don't. Do I need to create a global object in `Application_BeginRequest`? What approaches could I take to satisfy this requirement? Thanks

**edit:** this code outlines what I'm trying to do:

```
public class ResultsController : Controller
{
    private IPageConfiguration page;

    public ResultsController()
    {
        page = new PageConfiguration("?"); // needs value from query string
    }
}

public class FactsheetController : Controller
{
    private IPageConfiguration page;

    public FactsheetController()
    {
        page = new PageConfiguration("?"); // needs value from query string
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "have an interface to"? Do you mean that they all need to implement a certain interface?

Comment: I've updated my question to illustrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize.aspx) method. Have a base controller that defines this protected property and in the `Initialize` method set the value. Then as all your controllers derive from the base controller they will have access to the property.

Comment: +1 This is also a very nice approach even though it will make things a bit less transparent for my taste. Of course it has to be coupled with base controller class as well. But it will actually work faster than using action filters. (I'd vote twice if I could, because this is the optimal way of doing it)

Answer (score 3):

### Use action filter and base controller functionality

The easiest way would be to create an action filter. Do these:

1. Create a base controller class that defines this property
2. Write an action filter that is able to parse request's query string and populates base controller's property. Don't forget to set this action filter attribute's inheritance to `true`.
3. Attach action filter (attribute) to controller class

This way you will be able to make query string processing generic as well as automated, because you won't have to attach this action filter to all actions. It will already be attached to all child controller classes by means of inheritance.

Comment: @Jakob: Happens even to the best of... you... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, creating a global object strikes me as problematic since you might process multiple requests at once.  Creating an object in the session state would be a little better since MVC serializes all requests in a session by default, but you could still run into concurrency problems in the future.  Honestly, I think the best way is just to create the object in every action method that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use action filters.  You can see a simple example [here](http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/223).